# Local maximum image code not working for different images

Tags: computer-vision, scikit-image

I've been tinkering with local maximum finder for images code I found on [scikit-image.org](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_peak_local_max.html)

While the code works good with the set data.coins() image they used..

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsXlo.png)

.. whenever I try to input any of my pictures, the code just does not do the trick.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW9FD.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXyPY.png)

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mgrf.png)

```
im = skimage.img_as_float(skimage.io.imread('test.png'))
```

^ how I'm inputting the image.

It clearly applies the filter but for some reason can't find the maximums.

Don't know what I'm missing here, I tried changing the maximum filter size along with the min_distance from the peak_local_max but it does nothing.

I tried printing out the coordinates found with peak_local_max but the array is empty for all my images, so it basically doesn't find any maximums for some reason.

Anyone has an idea what that reason is?

Comment: Another thing, this is what the code says:
# image_max is the dilation of im with a 20*20 structuring element
# It is used within peak_local_max function
# Comparison between image_max and im to find the coordinates of local maxima
Where the hell is that comparison between "image_max" and "im" being done?? It says that image_max is used withing peak_local_max but I do not see any connection between these two

Comment: Can you provide your source images and a complete code snippet so that we can experiment? Another option is to try `morphology.local_maxima`.